# G++: fatal error: no input files

Tags: opencv, g++

Hi Im trying to display the lena.jpg which is the first demostration for Instant OpenCV Starter Book.

I can build and play 'hello world' easy enough.

The problem code

```
    // opencv header files
    #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
    #include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
    // namespaces declaration
    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;
    // create a variable to store the image
    Mat image;
    int main( int argc, char** argv )
    {
    // open the image and store it in the 'image' variable
    // Replace the path with where you have downloaded the image
    // image=imread("<path to image">/lena.jpg");
    image=imread("/home/nigel/Documents/ffmpeg/tests/lena.jpg");
    // create a window to display the image
    namedWindow( "Display window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    // display the image in the window created
    imshow( "Display window", image );
    // wait for a keystroke
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
    }
```

The error

```
    g++ -Wall -fexceptions 'pkg-config --cflags opencv' -g "pkg-config --cflags
    opencv' -c/home/nigel/Drone/Test2/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/Drone/Test2/main.o
    g++:fatal error:no input files
    compilation terminated
    process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
```

I have tried different paths for the lena.jpg, I changed the lena.jpg from lena.pnm not sure if I have the path right maybe ?

New to using OpenCv would appreciate some help

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when no source code file is passed in to g++. This leads me to believe there is an error in your command line arguments.

Some spots to look at:

It looks like there may be a stray quote before the second pkg-config in the line

```
 'pkg-config --cflags opencv' -g "pkg-config --cflags opencv'
```

It also looks like you are missing a space between the -c and the /home/.../main.cpp

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer,                                      The error is just what the Build log on codeblock IDE is producing, I have not generated this,